Pass shared value prop to children component (list of items + animated selected boolean prop)
My FontPicker is rendering a list of FontItem components.
Each FontItem should receive a boolean prop selected.
Since my selectedFont, controlled in the FontPicker, is an animated value (useSharedValue), is there any correct way to pass the selected prop to my child without doing the selected comparison inside each child component?

  const {
    selectedFont,
    onPressItem,
    onScroll,
    onMomentumScrollEnd,
  } = useFontPicker(scrollRef, { fonts, activeFont, itemWidth, onPick });

  const renderFonts = () =>
    fonts.map((font, index) => {
      const fontProps = {
        key: font,
        fontFamily: font,
        selectedFont, // <---- How to avoid passing the selected font? I mean, how can we pass just a boolean prop accessing the most up-to-date selectedFont.value??
        style: [fontItemStyles.container, fontItemStyle],
        textStyle: fontItemTextStyle,
        onPress: onPressItem(index),
      };

      return <FontItem {...fontProps} />;
    });

function FontItem({
  fontFamily,
  selectedFont, // <--- what about receiving a selected boolean prop instead?
  style = styles.container,
  textStyle,
  onPress,
}) {
  const { colors } = useTheme();

  const selected = useDerivedValue(() => selectedFont.value === fontFamily); // <--- How do we calculate this on the parent's .map??

  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const backgroundColor = selected.value ? colors.onSurface : colors.backdrop;

    return { backgroundColor };
  });

  const animatedTextStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const color = selected.value ? colors.primary : colors.onSurface;

    return { color };
  });

  const handleOnPress = () => {
    onPress?.(fontFamily);
  };

  const renderSample = () => (
    <Animated.Text style={[{ fontFamily }, animatedTextStyle, textStyle]}>
      Aa
    </Animated.Text>
  );

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleOnPress}>
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          animatedStyle,
          globalStyles.centeredContainer,
          style,
        ]}
      >
        {renderSample()}
      </Animated.View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}




How about just passing the compared value to the child elements.
const renderFonts = () =>
    fonts.map((font, index) => {
      const fontProps = {
        key: font,
        fontFamily: font,
        selected: selectedFont.value == font, // here
        style: [fontItemStyles.container, fontItemStyle],
        textStyle: fontItemTextStyle,
        onPress: onPressItem(index),
      };

      return <FontItem {...fontProps} />;
    });

Then selected prop will be a boolean value that you can use on <FontItem />
